# Point/Cell selection in paraview using coordinates, for script

Tags: paraview

I am actually developping a small script for making an automatic postprocessing of the output data of my simulation using Paraview. I want to select a specific point/cell and then make a plot over time. Since I want the point to be an input given to my script (coordinates of the point), I have been trying using Probe Location.

The problem that I have is that the script finds my point but when applying the Plot Over Time filter, no point/cell is selected. In  fact, when doing it "by hand", after finding my point/cell, I have to click in the spreadsheet on the output of the Probe Location.

I am pretty sure there has to be an easy way to do that, but I have not found it yet...

Comment: http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2010-April/017009.html this may help you

Comment: I could not get it to work with your link but thank you anyways. However I found a way to do it. After selecting my point/cell using a Probe Location filter, when using the standard filter Plot Over Time, the argument "selection=None" should be replaced by "selection = SelectionPoints(query='id==0'), so that the selected point/cell is the output of the filter probe location (with id=0)

Comment: You may want to add it as an actual answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

After selecting my point/cell using a Probe Location filter, when using the standard filter Plot Over Time, the argument `selection=None` should be replaced by `selection = SelectionPoints(query='id==0')`, so that the selected point/cell is the output of the filter probe location (with id=0)